# Regex that wil match after keyword and before question mark

Tags: javascript, regex, between

I'm getting stuck on regex101 with the following test string:

https://localhost:8443/site/recipes/recepten-zoeken/menugang:hoofdgerecht/soort:italiaans/seizoen:winter?Nrpp=24

I'm trying to match everything in between: recepten-zoeken/ and ?

My current tries lead me nowhere as i'm very novice writing regexes. Anyone wanting to chip in?

This is what I currently have:

.(?=([^/recepten-zoeken/]?)*$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capturing group.(`()` brackets indicates capturing group)

**Capture upto last question mark**

Try this regex `\/recepten-zoeken\/(.*)\?`

*Explanation:-*

- `\/` Match forward slash
- `recepten-zoeken` Match literally
- `\/` Match forward slash
- `(.*)` Capture in a group all value(except new line) upto last question mark in string(This will contain your value)
- `\?` Match literally

```js
//-------------------------select upto last ? -----------------------------

str = "https://localhost:8443/site/recipes/recepten-zoeken/menugang:hoofdgerecht/soort:italiaans/seizoen:winter?Nrpp=24";
var myRegexp = /\/recepten-zoeken\/(.*)\?/;
console.log(myRegexp.exec(str)[1]);
```

**Capture upto first question mark**

Try this regex `\/recepten-zoeken\/([^?]*)\?`.

*Explanation:-*

- `\/` Match forward slash
- `recepten-zoeken` Match literally
- `\/` Match forward slash
- `([^?]*)` Capture in a group all value(except ?) upto first question mark in string(This will contain your value)(here [^?] means match any character except `?`)
- `\?` Match literally

```js
//-------------------------select upto first ? -----------------------------

var str = "https://localhost:8443/site/recipes/recepten-zoeken/menugang:hoofdgerecht/soort:italiaans/seizoen?:winter?Nrpp=24";
var myRegexp = /\/recepten-zoeken\/([^?]*)\?/;
console.log(myRegexp.exec(str)[1]);
```

Comment: If there are two `?` in the string, this will not correctly match

Comment: this will match upto last question mark, there is no indication in question what it want as output when there are multiple `?`

Comment: @ctwheels my mistake

Comment: No worries, just indicate that that's the case. Also, introduce a way to fix it so that it matches up to the first question mark if that's the intended result. It'll better help explain your answer and provide the OP with appropriate information for choosing the answer that best answers their question. Keep your existing answer (in case that's what the OP is looking for), just introduce a second regex to allow up to first `?` matching. You are right, there is no indication in question what output should be should there be multiple `?`

Comment: Looks more complete now! :) You may consider separating the two snippets into two different ones instead of combined into the same snippet for clarity purposes.

Comment: @ctwheels thanks for suggestions. updated the answer

Comment: Looks great! :)

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I like the explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Try capturing your values in a capturing group:

[`recepten-zoeken\/([^?]+)\?`](https://regex101.com/r/2eG2Z2/1)

**Explanation**

- `recepten-zoeken` Match literally
- `\/` Match forward slash
- `([^?]+)` Capture in a group a negated character class `[^` which will match NOT a question mark. (This will contain your value)
- `\?` Match literally

```js
var s = "https://localhost:8443/site/recipes/recepten-zoeken/menugang:hoofdgerecht/soort:italiaans/seizoen:winter?Nrpp=24"
console.log(s.match(/recepten-zoeken\/([^?]+)\?/)[1])
```

Credits to [ctwheels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3600709/ctwheels)  for providing the snippet and comment.

Comment: You forgot the `/`

Comment: @ctwheels Ah your posted it in a comment..you should post your answer! I will remove mine.

Comment: I don't mind, you can use it. You thought the same around the same time, I don't have rights to it ;) Just create a snippet though :) I removed my comment too

Comment: Was about to post it but you are fast! :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
var match = url.match(/\/recepten-zoeken\/([^?]+)\?/);
// match[1] == "menugang:hoofdgerecht/soort:italiaans/seizoen:winter"
```

This regex will match the first occurrence of `/recepten-zoeken/`, then it will start capturing all characters that are not question marks (`[^?]` is a negative character class which matches anything *not* in the class).

Note that it will also ensure that there is a question mark. If you want to support cases where there is no question mark, then just remove the final `\?`.

Your original regular expression only matches a single character (the `.`), then it tries to look ahead for characters that are not `c`, `e`, `k`, `/` or between `n` and `z`.