# Cut prefix and suffix from word by regex

Tags: javascript, regex

can you help me write regex which gives me word without specified prefix and suffix?

Every word starts with dot (.) and ends with 'Zacher', e.g:

- .mobileZacher => output should be mobile
- .carZacher => output should be car
- .StevenZacher => => output should be Steven

I tried this `str.replace(/(?:.)|(?:Zacher)/, '')` but it replace only dot

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881450/regex-that-wil-match-after-keyword-and-before-question-mark/49881665#49881665

Comment: I've added more information in my answer in case you want to learn and understand more about RegEx.

Have fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try with following regex:

```
str.replace(/\.(.+?)Zacher/, '$1')
```

We're looking for dot character, then match everything to the first occurence of `Zacher` and replace it with the string between those.

You can also replace `(.+?)` part (which accepts any char) with `([a-zA-Z]+?)` to match only letters.

Or make it even case insensitive with `i`:

```
str.replace(/\.([a-z]+?)Zacher/i, '$1')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would extract the group between . and Zacher using this RegEx:

```
\.(.*)Zacher
```

The backslash is used to [escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) the . character.

It will basically tell RegEx not to interpret the . as a jolly character (its standard function in RegEx) but as a simple ".".

Then I'd use it in a string replace.
Since we want to extract the 1st (and only) group extracted we'll use $1:

```
str.replace(/\.(.*)Zacher/, '$1')
```

If you want to know more this kind of result is obtained using RegEx grouping function.
Grouping function syntax makes uses of parenthesis (something_in_here).

Here's a brief explanation from [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references):

> (x) Matches x and remembers the match. These are called capturing groups.
>
> For example, /(foo)/ matches and remembers "foo" in "foo bar".
>
> The capturing groups are numbered according to the order of left parentheses of capturing groups, starting from 1. The matched substring can be recalled from the resulting array's elements [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references), ..., [n] or from the predefined RegExp object's properties $1, ..., $9.
>
> Capturing groups have a performance penalty. If you don't need the matched substring to be recalled, prefer non-capturing parentheses (see below).

I suggest you to experiment with your RegEx using [RegExr](https://regexr.com).

If you want learn more while doing exercises [RegExOne](https://regexone.com) was of great help for me.